# Является ли нижеприведённое словосочетание вводной или вставной конструкцией?

Tags: вводные-слова, вставная-конструкция

...принадлежащих, **как сейчас модно говорить**, к...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это вводное предложение: ***...принадлежащих, как сейчас модно говорить, к...***

Эту тему можно посмотреть у Розенталя: [**Вводные и вставные конструкции**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#).

1. **Вводные предложения сходны по семантике** с вводными словами и сочетаниями.
   Запятыми выделяются вводные предложения следующих типов: <...> 3) предложения, присоединяемые посредством **союзов или союзных слов:**
   *Я, **как несомненно можете по мне видеть**, человек совсем незначительный* (Леск.); ***Как выражаются моряки**, ветер крепчал* (Ч.)...
2. **Вставные предложения и словосочетания**, внося в основное предложение дополнительные сведения (замечания, уточнения, пояснения, поправки и т. д.), иногда **резко выпадают** из синтаксической структуры целого.

**В отличие от вводных предложений**, они обычно не выражают отношения говорящего к высказываемой мысли, не содержат общей оценки сообщения, указания на его источник, на связь с другими сообщениями и т. п.

Вставные конструкции находятся в середине либо в конце предложения и выделяются скобками или тире.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно "Словарю вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений" O.A.Остроумовой и О.Д.Фрамполь это *предложение*, которое употребляется в функции вводного в значении «ссылка на общепринятые формулировки».

Answer (score 0):

Это вводное источника сообщения: это сочетание соответствует общему значению этой подсовокупности вводных и оно, как и все вводные, относится к последующей части предложения, а не как вставная конструкция — к предшествующей либо вообще ни к какой.